# Customizing CSH prompt

Tags: command-line, csh

I'm using the directions [here](http://www.understudy.net/custom.html#C_shell) to customize my CSH prompt. Here's what I'm using:

```
set prompt="\n%{\033[1;32m%}%m %{\033[36m%}${cwd}$ %{\033[0m%} "
```

First of all, the ${cwd} part isn't giving the full path to the directory I'm in, only the full path to the directory I'm in when .cshrc was sourced. How do I display the current directory?

Secondly, if I don't include the space at the end of the string the color of the text I type is changed to the color of the directory from the previous part. Is there anyway to do this without adding the space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code solved both of my problems.

```
set prompt="\n%{\033[0;32m%}%n@%m:%{\033[0;33m%}%~%{\033[1;30m%}>%{\033\[1;37m%} "
```

Comment: So, in other words, you used `%~`? Could you make that explicit in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

In C Shell, add the following lines to your .cshrc:

make a command doprompt that sets the prompt to the working directory

```
alias doprompt 'set prompt="`pwd` "'
```

set the prompt the first time around

```
doprompt
```

alias the cd command to change directories and reset the prompt

```
alias cd 'chdir !* || doprompt'
```

Comment: The doprompt command works fine. However, the cd alias causes problems. When I add that alias to my .cshrc, when I type cd it says `.cshrc: Not a directory`.